# Regular Expression to trim just the last () from sentence

Tags: c#, regex

I am having difficulty to figure out a regular expression. 
I have sentences:
"1A11 - Vehicle Engine Control Unit (VECU) (Behind Plate)"
"1A1K5 - Vehicle Rear View (Front View)"
I want to trim my sentence from (----), I have this regular expression to do so  "@"\s*([^)]*)" but the problem with this one is that like in my first sentence the (VECU) is the abbreviation so I need to keep it. But this regular expression doesn't work if i have 2 () (). How can I modify my regular expression 2 trim only that last () from the sentence?

```
 if (!reportMode)
 {
     //Look line by line for Title                               
     stream = GetStream(files);
     List<String> fileContent = new List<String>();
     using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
     {
        String line = "";
        Boolean isInThere = false;
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
           line = sr.ReadLine();
           if (line.Contains(title))
           {
              //check for exact match
              Int32 index = line.IndexOf(" - ");
              String revisedLine = line.Substring(index + 3).Trim();
              String str = Regex.Replace(revisedLine, @"\s*\([^\)]*\)", "").Trim();
              if (Regex.IsMatch(str, String.Format("^{0}$", title)))
                  isInThere = true;
           }
           fileContent.Add(line);
      }
```

Comment: Do you have sentences within a text body, or do you have an array of strings each of which is a sentence?

Comment: Do you know the abbreviations? If you do, you could exclude them with an assertion. `\s*\((?!(?:VECU|ABCD|EFGH)\))[^)]*\)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could anchor  the regexp at the end of the line. This is usually done adding a '$' sign at the end: "\s*\([^\)]*\)$". If the closing parenthesis is the last character of the string this should do. Otherwise you can add expression to ignore whitespace.

(Fixed regexp syntax, thanks Patrick)

--
MaxP

Comment: That should be ``"\s*\([^\)]*\)$"``. Note the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to remove a parenthetical expression that is last but can appear not only at the end, you may use

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\s*\([^()]*\)(?=[^()]*$)");
String str = rx.Replace(revisedLine, "").Trim();
```

REGEX:

- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace symbols
- `\([^()]*\)` - round bracket followed by any number of characters other than `)` or `(`
- `(?=[^()]*$)` - A lookahead that checks if before the end of string there is no `(` nor `)` symbols.

Mind that you do not need to escape the round brackets inside the character classes.